# Custom MGLAnnotationView using Mapbox for IOS

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I am very confused why this is displaying the default image instead of a round blue circle over New York. Any insight about this as well as when the default image is used will be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupMapview()
    }

    func setupMapview(){
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.74699, longitude: -73.98742), zoomLevel: 9, animated: false)
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.77014, longitude: -73.97480)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        mapView.delegate = self
    }


    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        print("CORDINATE")
        print(annotation.coordinate)
        if annotation is MGLPointAnnotation {
            print("SET\n\n\n")
            let av = RoundedAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "ResuseIdentifier")
            av.configure()
            return av
        }
        return nil
    }
}

class RoundedAnnotationView: MGLAnnotationView{
    func configure(){
        backgroundColor = .blue
        layer.cornerRadius = 24
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Output: 
[iPhone_Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv7mN.png)
[print_statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7ZVB.png)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo? `reuseIdentifier: "ResuseIdentifier"` looks like it should be `reuseIdentifier: "ReuseIdentifier"`.

Answer (score 0):

The standard default annotation is being shown in NY because that is exactly what you are adding to the map in `setupMapview`. If you want the map to display the user's location, you have to tell it to do so:

```
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

mapView.showsUserLocation = true // This needs to be set explicitly.

mapView.delegate = self
```

As usual, when you want to have access to the user's location you have to ask permission by inserting the correct flag in the `info.plist`:

```
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
```

along with some kind of explanatory string:

```
"We'd like to track you with our satellite."
```

If you are running your app on the simulator you can create a custom location:

Simulator -> Features -> Location -> Custom Location...

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to get a literal blue circle AnnotationView, not the location. I found out why it was behaving this way and I attached the link to the solution

Answer (score 0):

Annotations should be added after the map has completely loaded. I have a more detailed step by step solution: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/16492